# Producing a batch agenda excluding habits

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I've set up a cron job to email myself my agenda every morning; it just runs

```
emacs -batch -eval '(org-batch-agenda "a")'
```

I'd like to set up a custom agenda to exclude all habits (i.e. those with STYLE: habit), but I couldn't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try piping to AWK and remove all lines with 'HABIT' before you email it.

`<emacs command> | awk '!/HABIT/' | <email>`

Comment: Thanks - that's a nice idea, but unfortunately the agenda that gets emailed doesn't write "habit" next to any of the habits, so this doesn't work (at least naively).

Comment: Thanks again - this made me think about it again and figure out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following works: use a custom init.el file, and add:

(require 'org-habit)
(custom-set-variables
 '(org-habit-show-habits nil))